# Secured textField encrypt arabic numbers

Tags: swift, uitextfield, arabic

Secured textField encrypt arabic numbers and letters as shown in the following:

Any idea what may cause this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems more like a bug in a Secured UITextField

Comment: I can't reproduce this. How are you producing this secure keyboard? How are you implementing the show/hide button?